# Responsive video size (Vimeo)

Tags: html, vimeo, embedded-video

I am embedding a video (from Vimeo) onto my survey. I am using the embed code from Vimeo which is responsive. It looks great when viewing on my mobile, however when viewing on my laptop it takes up the entire screen.

Is there a way keep it responsive so that when viewed on mobile it stays the same size, but when on laptop it is half the size?

This is the responsive embed code from Vimeo that I am using:

```
<div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/581420395?badge=0&amp;autopause=0&amp;player_id=0&amp;app_id=58479" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" title="Neck Flexion Test"></iframe></div><script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
```

Fixed Embed Code:

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/581420395?badge=0&amp;autopause=0&amp;player_id=0&amp;app_id=58479" width="1920" height="1080" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen title="Neck Flexion Test"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

Responsive design is the change of objects according to the height and width of the devices. **@media** screen is used for responsive design in HTML text markup language. And this code takes 2 parameters for max height and max width. If the height and width are reached within the specified limits, the code block you have written will work and your web page will switch to the new design.

Instead of using an iframe tag in style blocks, you can give different properties to other iframe objects if you give the iframe tag an id and use it.

```
<style>
    #vimeo {
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    @media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
        #vimeo {
            width: 50%;
        }
    }
    
    @media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
        #vimeo {
            width: 25%;
        }
    }
</style>

    <body>
    <div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe id="vimeo" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/581420395?badge=0&amp;autopause=0&amp;player_id=0&amp;app_id=58479" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;"
            title="Neck Flexion Test"></iframe></div>
    <script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Lawis, that makes sense. Is there any chance you could please help me in specifically altering my current embed code (pasted in initial question) so that I could paste your amendment into my survey to see if it works? I want to reduce the video width size on all laptop screens by approx 50% (as it currently takes up the entire screens width), but keep size on mobile platforms normal / responsive (100% width)? I can provide exact resolution parameters for sizing on laptops if that helps (50% width). I have also added the fixed embed code from Vimeo to my initial question if this helps

Answer (score 0):

Anytime specific types of devices need to be targeted, [`@media` queries](https://dev.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries) will do so. Styles of laptop devices can be applied with

```
@media screen and (min-width: 992px)
```

<sup>This is not an accurate integration. Sizes of screens vary. [How to choose breakpoints?](https://uiuxlab.medium.com/the-most-used-responsive-breakpoints-in-2017-of-mine-9588e9bd3a8a)</sup>

I highly recommend removing properties from the [`style`](https://dev.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/style) attribute.

> Both inline styles and [`!important`](https://dev.mozilla.org/CSS/Specificity#the_!important_exception) are considered very **bad** practice, but sometimes you need the latter to override the former.
> <sub>MDN Web Docs | [Specifity](https://dev.mozilla.org/CSS/Specificity#how_!important_can_be_used)</sub>

```css
.video
{
  position: relative;
  padding: 56.25% 0 0 0;
}
.video iframe
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px)
{
  .video iframe
  {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="video">
  <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/581420395?badge=0&amp;autopause=0&amp;player_id=0&amp;app_id=58479" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen title="Neck Flexion Test">
  </iframe>
</div>
<script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
```

[<kbd>Interactive Code</kbd>](https://jsitor.com/Jy9UG_1Cj)

<sup>Code design is [Mobile-first](https://dev.mozilla.org/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Media_queries#active_learning_mobile_first_responsive_design). More information about [Using media queries](https://dev.mozilla.org/docs/CSS/Media_Queries).</sup>

Comment: Thanks for this Luko. Is there any chance you could please help me in specifically altering my current embed code (pasted in initial question) so that I could paste your amendment into my survey to see if it works? I want to reduce the video width size on all laptop screens by approx 50% (as it currently takes up the entire screens width), but keep size on mobile platforms normal / responsive (100% width)? I can provide exact resolution parameters for sizing on laptops if that helps (50% width).

Comment: The code represents the exact solution. In case you wish to have fixed ratio (`1920x1080`) on [`iframe`](https://dev.mozilla.org/HTML/Element/iframe "MDN Web Docs"), use [`aspect-ratio`](https://dev.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio "MDN Web Docs")`: 16/9` and remove the [`width`](https://dev.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/width "MDN Web Docs") and [`height`](https://dev.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/height "MDN Web Docs") attributes.

Comment: Thanks Luke. When I copy the script you have advised into the source option on my survey, it leaves part of it out when clicking confirm. See two pics below illustrating this (https://ibb.co/RB6kPgj <-- inserting the script), (https://ibb.co/Wz8L6C5 <-- what happens after I click confirm). Is there something I need to add to make it take the script properly?

Comment: I don't know what this survey is and the result doesn't correspond with the code. I can provide you the [correct result](https://jsitor.com/Jy9UG_1Cj "JSitor"). After slight resize it will apply the laptop styles.