# Responsive Vimeo DIV Embed to 80% Width on Page with Scrolling

Tags: html, css, video, iframe, embed

How can I make Vimeo's responsive video embed code fit within a container div set to 80% width? Despite my attempts, I have been unable to adjust the sizing to fit my needs. I am looking for a solution that will allow the video to respond well on all devices, including desktops, HDTVs, and mobile devices. Currently, the code sizes the video to 100%, but I want to maintain its responsiveness while placing it within a container div. Any suggestions?

```
<div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/#####?badge=0&amp;autopause=0&amp;player_id=0&amp;app_id=58479" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" ></iframe></div><script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
```

I found another article see [responsive vimeo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68610229/responsive-video-size-vimeo)

When I tried this technique however it still places the entire video full width on desktop, it does not reduce the width at all.  The responsive container does not have enough room for a button below the video.  Here's the code from the above article that claims to solve this problem:

```
.video
{
  position: relative;
  padding: 56.25% 0 0 0;
}
.video iframe
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px)
{
  .video iframe
  {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

<div class="video">
  <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/#?badge=0&amp;autopause=0&amp;player_id=0&amp;app_id=58479" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen title="Neck Flexion Test">
  </iframe>
</div>
<script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
```

I tried one more thing: to place another  tag outside of the container and set that tag to 80% of the width of the screen, but when I did this, it placed the button and all the text below it BEHIND the main video, which is unusable.

When I enclose the video inside of another container instead such as:

```
<div style="
                position: absolute;
                height: 80%; 
                width: 80%; 
                top: 10%; 
                left: 10%; 
">

### above vimeo code 

</div>
```

So I'm stuck... at the moment, I do not have a solution to place the video at 80% of screen width with a button below it.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You have used **position:absolute** ! this will remove the div from the natural flow of the page!

try to use this in place:

```
<div style="position:relative; width:80%; margin:10% auto 0;">
... your vimeo responsive embed code...
</div>
```

This should work perfectly like this sample: https://jsfiddle.net/gp1jo6Lt/

Comment: very close but there's a huge white space above the video now. the video needs to be at the top so there's room for a button below the video in the VSL.

Comment: I was able to fix it by removing the 'margin' and the 'auto' 0

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to parchambault for pointing in the right direction. This is the final code that works perfectly.

```
<center><div style="position:relative; width:80%;">

<!-- your vimeo responsive embed code -->

</div></center>
```

This way the video is also centered on the page.